# Multiplication of all nodes in a binary tree

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to multiply all nodes in a binary tree
but I'm only getting 0 as a result. My code is:

```
product_tree(nil,0).
product_tree(t(L,X,R), N):-
   product_tree(L,L1),
   product_tree(R,R2),
   N is X * L1 * R2.
```

Comment: For all `Any`: `0*Any =:= 0.`

Comment: (This is related to the reason mathematicians usually consider the product of an empty set to be 1, not 0.)

Comment: could you be more specific sir?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that in the base case, (when the tree is empty, in the first line), you are setting the result to 0. So when you get that base case, you are multiplying all your result by 0, which result is 0.

So, to fix that, try changing the 0 by 1 in the first line.